# How can I curve the top two corners of react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react native and I am using **react-navigation** & **react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs**.

All I want to do is curve the top-right corner and top-left corner of bottom tab bar.

My Code:

```
const screen1 = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: HomeScreen,
            style : {
                backgroundColor: 'black'
            }
        },
        About: AboutScreen,
        Scan: ScanScreen,
        Fav: AllScreen
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Home",
        activeColor: 'red',
        inactiveColor: 'blue',

        barStyle: {
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
            borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
            borderTopRightRadius: 15,
            borderTopColor: '#000',
            borderBottomColor: '#000',
            borderLeftColor: '#000',
            borderRightColor: '#000',
        },
    }
);
```

Comment: Could you please add codesandbox with you issue recreated?

Comment: @MikeRos could not recreate the problem min codesandbox. i think it doesn't support react native

Comment: I've setup a template for you in codesandbox ( https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-o2jxx ) 

Comment: @MikeRos after adding some dependencies, there is an error. As i am newbie, I couldn't solve it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not react-native pro but after debugging for some time i came up with solution by adding `overflow: 'hidden'` to barStyle. The problem lies in child div as it inherits background color which overlaps with your rounded border.

[image]

```
barStyle: {
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor:'orange',
            borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
            borderTopRightRadius: 15,
            borderColor: 'transparent',
            overflow: 'hidden',
        },
```

see working [snack.expo](https://snack.expo.io/@mikeros/basic-tabs-v3)

[image]